# How can I center buttons inside a DIV so there's the same space right and left of the four buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
            <div class="clearfix">
                <div>
                    <button>a</button>
                    <button>a</button>
                    <button>a</button>
                    <button>a</button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The buttons appear to the left and leave a space on the right of my outer DIV. How can I make it so the buttons center themselves leaving a space on the left and the right that is equal?

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question fully, are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/LFkaF/)?

Answer (score 1):

if you want all the buttons to be centered in the middle of your `div` and the rest of your available space to be divided between the left and the right, use `text-align:center` on the container.

```
------ ** ** ** ** ------
```

but if you want all the available space to be equally divided between the elements margin use a little trick involving `text-align:justify` and some pseudo elements.

I have 2 ways of dividing the space.

```
1) ** --- ** --- ** --- **

2) -- ** -- ** -- ** -- ** --    //I think this has the best visual output
```

you can see the difference and implementations in this [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3FRVJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: inline-block` and `text-align: center`.

```
.clearfix > div{
    text-align: center;
}

button{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Do you mean something similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/lee_gladding/YEptp/

Answer (score 0):

Like this with CSS:

```
.clearfix > div {
  text-align: center;
}
.clearfix button {
  display: inline-block; // this should be the default state, so it is probably not needed
}
```

One other thing, you must make sure the div inside `.clearfix` has a width. Otherwise there's nothing to center into.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this CSS:

```
.clearfix{
    width:500px;
    text-align:center;}
```

Refer the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/V6fxp/

Comment: Width isn't required (in case div is a block at 100%).

Comment: Width I added just for reference, this can/should be changed as per the layout

Answer (score 0):

According to your HTML:

```
button {
    display: inline-block;
}

div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

But I would encourage you to add some classes here, it's not a good idea to deal with such selectors for that kind of specific style.

Answer (score 0):

`margin: auto;` will give you horizontal and vertical centering as long as the element also has a specific width (for horizontal) and height (for vertical).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vQJ3L/

Update: another approach is to use [CSS3's calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/calc) to center the element. This has the advantage of being responsive:

http://jsfiddle.net/vQJ3L/3/

Answer (score -1):

```
.clearfix > div {
  text-align: center;
}


 <div class="clearfix">
                    <div>
                        <button>a</button>
                        <button>a</button>
                        <button>a</button>
                        <button>a</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Hope this helps you.